# How to Ignore a value in a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, linkedin-api

I'm trying to access a hash with all the values for each connection. Right now, it's `connections.values[1]` in order to bypass `_total`.

[image]

There are certain cases when `_total` doesn't show up for certain ppl, thus rendering the code above invalid.

I also tried `connections.values` by that spits out the value `450` instead off the actual connections. How do I make sure to ignore `_total : 450` in cases that it does appear and just access the persons information instead?

Comment: Not sure I get you, show us the code that isn't 'ignoring' it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lies in that the key name is "values" hash.values actually returns the values of a hash and that's an internal Ruby hash method.

Try using connections[:values] instead.